# How to use "Kafka Streams Binder" with "Functional Style" and DI?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_programming_model shows an example where the *input topic* can be set using the property `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process_in.destination`.

Now I want to use dependency injection, e.g.

```java
@Bean
public java.util.function.Consumer<KStream<Object, String>> process(JavaMailSender mailSender) {...}
```

When starting the application (based on Spring Boot) the property `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process_in.destination` is ignored, and instead the input topic `input` is subscribed.

EDIT: Here is the Kotlin code (without imports)

Mailer.kt:

```
@Configuration
class Mailer {
    @Bean
    fun sendMail(/*mailSender: JavaMailSender*/) = Consumer<KStream<Any, Mail>> { input ->
        input.foreach { _, mail -> println("mail = $mail") }
    }
}
```

Mail.kt:

```
data class Mail(var from: String = "", var to: String = "", var subject: String = "", var body: String = "")
```

Application.kt:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args) {
    }
}
```

application.yml::

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings.sendMail_in.destination: mail
  kafka.binder.configuration.listeners: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

Comment: Hi, any chance you can share more code or configuration? I would certainly like to take a look at what you are describing. The new functional features in the kafka streams binder are currently at the milestone stage. We would like to identify any issues with the way you are trying to autowire.

Comment: @sobychacko  please see the additional Kotlin code above.

Comment: do you notice this problem only when you uncomment the dependency injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues in the binder that didn't properly `autowire` the beans provided to a function/consumer `bean`. Latest snapshot solves those problems though. Please make sure that you are using the latest snapshot (`3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`). Here is a [sample application](https://github.com/schacko-samples/SO-57569358) that works with the same scenario that you provided.

Comment: Thank you, @sobychacko. Using the snapshot works fine. BTW, I also tried the new Bean DSL which also works fine.